# Magento 2 integration with External System via API

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.3, rest-api, soap-api-v2

I'm currently in process of creating a Magento 2 module that will handle and pull product data from external system into Magneto database using API requests (SOAP and REST)

Any guide or module recommendation would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think this tutorial will help you:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ext-best-practices/tutorials/create-integration-with-api.html

Answer (score 0):

You will have to implement/create an api code into your Magento in order to retrieve product data from third party external system. You can follow this Magento2 official doc https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/get-started/create-integration.html to create a rest webapi in your project.